# wso2 api manager Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 Error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, http-status-code-401

I'm using from wso2 api manager 4.1.0, when I try it out a method without entering username and password from Devportal, I get the following error but I want to handle the error and show the client a 401 error.
How can I do that?

```
<soapenv:Reason xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Index 0 out of bounds for length 0</soapenv:Text></soapenv:Reason>
```

Comment: Usually the product returns 401 with the correct error message when invalid credentials are provided for an API secured with Basic authentication. This seems to be a product bug when empty credentials are sent. 

Do you see the same error `Index 0 out of bounds for length 0` in the carbon logs as well? If so please report an issue in https://github.com/wso2/api-manager/issues

Comment: yes I get same error in wso2carbon.log, ok I report an issue.

Comment: https://github.com/wso2/api-manager/issues/1719